# Applescript on mavericks - damaged?

Tags: applescript, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I created a script in applescript using OSX Lion and am sharing it with people using yosemite/mavericks. They are saying that they are getting errors:

"The app is damaged and cannot be opened".

I'm pretty sure this is something to do with gatekeeper, e.g. http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14372but im wondering is there any way to resolve it (other than installing the OSX versions and saving the applescript to there?)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a gatekeeper issue then you can fix it in "System Preferences --> Security & Privacy --> General" tab in the "Allow apps downloaded from:" section. You can see there's 3 choices. The 3rd choice should allow your applescript to run so you'll need to ask your users to choose that gatekeeper setting. The middle choice could be used if you sign your app. Of course there's security issues involved here so you'll need to explain that to your users.

Good luck.